# Android: how can change the text color in custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this view called ButtonMultiline:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/ButtonMultilineCatalogTitle"
    android:text="title"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/ButtonMultilineCatalogSubtitle"
    android:text="subtitle"/>
```

I apply a background on this layout to change color on press:

```
<selector android:exitFadeDuration="200"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_large_normal" />
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <color android:color="@color/background_black_top" />
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_large_pressed" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_large_pressed" android:state_hovered="true" />
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_large_normal" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_large_normal" />
```

All works fine until here.

I want to change the both TextView color on press too, but when I add this line in both TextView, there is a crash on inflate problem on this *button_text_catalog.xml*:

```
<android:background="@drawable/button_text_catalog">
```

My *button_text_catalog.xml*:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:color="@color/white" android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:color="@color/theme_primary"/>
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: I think you must use TextColor attribute, not background

Comment: @anthony, in your style.xml add <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/button_text_catalog</item> line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

button_text_catalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
    <!-- activated -->
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
    <!-- checked -->
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/white"/>

    <!-- default -->
    <item android:color="@color/theme_primary"/>

</selector>
```

in Style.xml

add `<item name="android:textColor">@drawable/button_text_catalog</item>`